# Where find good json formater and validation?

Tags: microsoft-windows, json

Emacs 26.1. Windows 10

It's has function `json-pretty-print` . But it not enough for me.
Has any another better json formater and validator?
I mean the next.

Suppose I has error on json on **line 26**. I missed **","**.
But `json-pretty-print` get me strange error message:

```
Json readtable error: 93
```

[image]

I don't understand this message. What does it mean?
Why simple not get message something like this:

```
Error: Parse error on line 26:
...n1_FR"           }       ]   }   "loyalty": true,    "u
-------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got 'STRING'
```

So that is the reason why I need better json validator and formater.

Comment: I update my post with explain what I mean "good".

Answer (score 0):

I'm really curious about *why* you feel `json-pretty-print` is not good enough.

Perhaps you don't like needing to call it manually?  You could set it to run whenever you save the file:

```
(add-hook
 'json-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
   (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'json-pretty-print-buffer t t)))
```

If you'd still like an alternative, I highly recommend [prettier-mode](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-emacs).  It's a minor mode that runs the file through [prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier) on save.  In circumstances with invalid JSON it does give you diagnostic output (but does not enforce strict JSON AFAIK.  For example:

```
prettier errors:
[error] stdin: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected "," (4:7)
[error]   2 |   "foo": {
[error]   3 |       "bar": "baz"
[error] > 4 |       "blah": "blooh"
[error]     |       ^
[error]   5 |   }
[error]   6 | }
[error]   7 |
```

Comment: I updated my post.

Comment: I install prettier-mode. How I can validate json? What is the command for this?

Comment: Emacs 26.1, Windows 10.